# Changing a few values in a hash

Tags: ruby, hash

Say I have a hash:

```
h = {"upper_left", 1, "upper_right", 2, "lower_left", 3, "lower_right", 4 }
```

and I want to get:

```
{"upper_left", nil, "upper_right", nil, "lower_left", 3, "lower_right", 4 }
```

so I create a method that takes a hash:

```
def edge_adjust(hash)
  hash["upper_left", nil, "upper_right", nil] 
end
```

but I get the error:

```
wrong number of arguments (4 for 1)
```

I know it's giving the elements of the hash one at a time or my method is broke, not sure how to get what I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to use [merge](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-i-merge) method to replace first hash values with the values from the second hash:

```
def edge_adjust(hash)
  hash.merge( {"upper_left", nil, "upper_right", nil})
end

edge_adjust({"upper_left", 1, "upper_right", 2, "lower_left", 3, "lower_right", 4 }) 
# returns: {"upper_left", nil, "upper_right", nil, "lower_left", 3, "lower_right", 4 }
```

Please not that if first hash does not contain some values from the second hash then these values will be created:

```
edge_adjust({"lower_left", 3, "lower_right", 4 }) 
# returns: {"upper_left", nil, "upper_right", nil, "lower_left", 3, "lower_right", 4 } as well
```

Comment: +1. a merge is exactly the OP was asking for. You may use the "normal" hash syntax, this won't work in 1.9

Comment: @tokland I think it depends on the regularity of the new value. If the new value is a constant (as in this case `nil`), then using merge, which requires you to write down all the new values, is redundant.

Comment: @sawa: `hash.merge(Hash[["upper_left", "upper_right"].map { |k| [k, nil] }])`. Using Facets' mash: `hash.merge(["upper_left", "upper_right"].mash { |k| [k, nil] })`

Answer (score 2):

Your Hash initialization is wrong. I suppose you want something like:

```
h = Hash["upper_left", 1, "upper_right", 2, "lower_left", 3, "lower_right", 4]

["upper_left", "upper_right"].each{|k| h[k] = nil}
```

Comment: @sawa I'm not intending to initialize the hash in the method, it's suppose to be a parameter that I am adjusting the contents of. Sorry if my newbieness presents confusion

Comment: This worked:

    `def edge_adjust(hash)`
      `hash.merge!({"upper_left" => nil, "upper_right" => nil})`
    `end`

Comment: @steve, don't force inplace updates unless needed. merge is enough.

Comment: @tokland Thank you, merge was sufficient without the bang.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, `Hash#[]` is an accessor method, not something that will modify the data. It takes only one argument, the key, and will return the value stored in that location, if any. This is not to be confused with `Hash.[]` which is a class method to create new hashes.

If you want to mass-assign values to the hash, you have a few options, but the most straight-forward is:

```
 # Spin through a list of keys to remove...
 %w[ upper_left upper_right ].each do |k|
   # ...and nil out each entry.
   h[k] = nil
 end
```

You might also try and use a pattern to zap out any entries you don't want:

```
 # Delete all keys that begin with "upper_"
 h.delete_if { |k| k.match(/^upper_/) }
```

Note that this actually deletes the keys as well, so you can still get `nil` when fetching, but they are not present in `h.keys`.